# Behaviour subject automatic updating value with out subscribe

Tags: angular

I am trying to  set a value to behaviour  subject  in one component and  i want 
to access the same value in another component but my value is automatic updating the value

```
   public workitemTemp: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);  

   setWorkitemTemp(value: any) {
      this.workitemTemp.next(value);
   }  

   this._sharingService.getWorkItemTempObj().subscribe(res => {
        if (res != null) {
          this.showEnvelope(res)
        }
   });
```

Comment: try `public workitemTemp = new Subject<any>(); `

Comment: Could you provide more of your code and describe the problem in further detail ?

Comment: @Korte  i am navigation a component based on object  details and assign same object to  behaviour subject a  and receive the same object in ng oninit
before my component load  the observerable is already loaded
i want  to load the object when my component render

Comment: @sraveennagunuri please provide some more of your code

Answer (score 0):

Use a new variable as Observable and not method which return a Observable. Then just subscribe to that variable. Try this:

```
 public workitemTemp: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
 public WorkItemTempObj= this.workitemTemp.asObservable();


  setWorkitemTemp(value: any) {
    this.workitemTemp.next(value);
  }  

  this._sharingService.getWorkItemTempObj.subscribe(res => {
     if (res != null) {
        this.showEnvelope(res)
    }
 });
```

Comment: its not working since  public workitemTempobj is updating before my component is loaded
and same  object is subscribed and  loading once again
my aim  is to load only when my component is loaded